# Нарушение прав доступа С++

Tags: c++

0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xFDFDFDFD.
Не знаю что делать, пишет: **Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x0034285B в Двумерный динамический массив.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xFDFDFDFD.
**

```
srand(time(0));
    int ROWS = 4;
    int COLS = 5;
    int** arr = new int* [ROWS];

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[COLS];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; i++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 20;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }




    delete[]arr;
}
```

Comment: *"Не знаю что делать"* - 1) устранять копипасту `for (int j = 0; j < COLS; i++)` 2) всегда перед разыменованием проверять индекс на корректность 3) не использовать сырые указатели

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подробно объяснить свои слова ? просто я ещё студент и не до конца вас понял )

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 20;
    }
}
```

Опечатка во вложенном цикле

Comment: но какая ? Вроде бы всё правильно  написано, всё по несколько раз проверял

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < COLS; i++)
Приращение переменной i. Такой цикл будет крутится бесконечно, если бы не было ошибки доступа